# why "&", "+" characters are not encoded in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using this following code snippet to encode the string, which i need to send to REST Api's

```
 NSString* content=@"Test &a=b";
 NSString* encodedString=[content stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"encodedString :%@",encodedString);
```

And got the following output

```
**Test%20&a=b**
```

Why "&" and "=" characters are not encoded?

But this issue is solved by using "CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes" method

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `NSASCIIStringEncoding` will convert to 7-bit Ascii, which `+` is 43 and `&` is 38.  Since they are valid 7-bit ASCII chars, I would not expect them to be converted with what you have.  Source -

While CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes will

> replacing certain characters with the equivalent percent escape
>   sequence based on the specified encoding

Sources:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSASCIIStringEncoding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII